# Increment/Decrements in a custom listview

Tags: java, android, xml

for a project of mine, i want to implement the kind of counter that this app uses (the white one, mine is the blue one). I have created the custom listview with the everything in place but for some reason, when i press either the + button or the - button, the increments do not work for that specific item. instead it increments items at either the bottom or other items that are not the one i pressed the button for. I have tried using switch cases and onClickMethod for the specific position in getView but it still just does not work. My question is how can i increment just for that specific item without it affecting others counts? I'm doing the increasing and decreasing of count in my getView method of my customAdapter class that extends baseAdapter. I feel like the problem is more logical and less code wise. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int pos = position;
    View myView = convertView;

    //if this is the first time coming here
    if(myInfater == null) {
        myInfater = (LayoutInflater) myActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    if (myView == null) {
        myView = myInfater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    }



    ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
    TextView itemName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    TextView itemPrice = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);

    //stuff in linear layout
    itemCount = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemCount);
    decreaseButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemDecrement);
    increaseButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemIncrement);



    final GroceryItem myItem = groceryItemList.get(position);
    myItem.setCount(myCount);
    myCount = myItem.getCount();
    globalPos = position; //gets the position so we can use it in onClick

    itemImage.setImageResource(myItem.getImageId());
    itemName.setText(myItem.getName());
    itemPrice.setText("$" + String.valueOf(myItem.getPrice()));
    itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myCount));


    decreaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (myCount != 0) {
                itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myCount--));
                System.out.println("decrease method count = " + myItem.getCount());
            }
        }
    });

    increaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myCount++));
            //myItem.setCount(getCount() + 1);
            System.out.println("count = " + myItem.getCount());

        }
    });

    return myView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    System.out.println("My count is " + myCount); //for debugging

    switch (v.getId()) {
        //the - button was pressed
        case R.id.itemDecrement:
            if (myCount != 0) {
                System.out.println("decrement button pressed"); //for debugging
                myCount --; //decrement myCount
                groceryItemList.get(globalPos).setCount(myCount);
                itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myCount)); //update the count
            }
            break;
        case R.id.itemIncrement:
            System.out.println("increment button pressed"); //for debugging
            myCount++; //increment myCount
            groceryItemList.get(globalPos).setCount(myCount);
            itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myCount));
            break;
    }

}
```

[image: This is my program]

[image]

Comment: Where is myCount declared?

Comment: everything not declared in the method is declared as a global variable

Comment: Store `myCount` in your `GroceryItem`. The count is on a per item basis and set `GroceryItem` as a tag of the `View` that goes up and down.

Comment: How would you do that? can you show me an example please

Answer (score 0):

**Each item needs its own count**, first remove the `myCount` declaration. Add this code snippet in `getView`:

```
final GroceryItem myItem = groceryItemList.get(position);
//myItem.setCount(myCount);
//myCount = myItem.getCount();
//globalPos = position;
decreaseButton.setTag(myItem);
increaseButton.setTag(myItem);
itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myItem.getCount()));
```

In your `onClick` use this:

```
GroceryItem gItem = (GroceryItem)v.getTag();
int myCount = gItem.getCount();
TextView itemCountText = v.getParent().findViewById(R.id.itemCount);
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.itemDecrement:
   myCount = Math.max(myCount--, 0);
   break;
case R.id.itemIncrement:
   // Maximum quantity of 99
   myCount = Math.min(myCount++, 99);
   break;
}

myItem.setCount(myCount);
itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myCount));
```

Comment: it gave me a fatal error in because the itemCountText was null and we are trying to set the text 
also, v.getParent().findViewById() didn't work so i used v.findVIewById() instead

Answer (score 0):

```
 itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myCount--));
```

the globally (you said its defined globally in your comment) defined `myCount` will decrease itself by value 1.
so first of all you have to maintain an `ArrayList` or something to maintain count for each item and set its initial value 0 by `myItem.setCount(0);`

and then when you inside decreaseButton listener you have to update count value for that particular position like this

```
  decreaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // decrease value for specific position, supposes it's a list of string type .
                    myItem.set(position, myCount--);
                    itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myItem.getCount()));

            }
        });
```

and increase count for the specific position and update on increase button's listener

```
  increaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  // increase value for specific position, supposes it's a list of string type.
                   myItem.set(position, myCount++);
                   itemCount.setText(String.valueOf(myItem.getCount()));

    }
});
```

the bottom line is you have to maintain a list and then update it accordingly for that position and whenever you want to get these value just loop through it and get every value from list.